# Key enable after another key was pressed before

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make it so that pressing 'r' key will only work after the user pressed 'enter' anytime before. But right now in #1 I can only press 'r' key if I'm holding 'enter' key. I tried in #2 but then the user can just press 'r' without pressing 'enter'.

```
#1
run = True  
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN] or [pygame.K_KP_ENTER]:
        print("Do something")
        if keys[pygame.K_r]:
            print("Do something")
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit() 

#2
run = True  
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN] or [pygame.K_KP_ENTER]:
        print("Do something")
    if keys[pygame.K_r]:
        print("Do something")
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You could create a variable as `enter_pressed = False` at the start of the loop, and after the enter key is pressed re-declare it with a `True` value then use `if keys[pygame.K_r] and enter_pressed` in method#2 to make sure the `r` key only works after using the `enter`

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to do.
First you need to create a new bool, for example `pressed`. And then set it to `False`. Then check if key enter is pressed. If it is then set bool `pressed` to `True`. And then check if key r is pressed and if bool `pressed` is `True`.
So your code should look like this:

```
pressed = False
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
        pressed = True
    if keys[pygame.K_r] and pressed:
        print("Do something")
    pygame.display.update()
```

I hope it helped!

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help!